Why is my file upload not saving to the database?
I am trying to create a post form where the user can upload an image and the image isn't being saved as well as the asset model isn't creating a new entry. I am using Livewire and Laravel's Filesystem. I read in the Laravel docs to use hashName() as it is more secure. I am not sure why the method is not storing the file.
<form wire:submit.prevent="store_post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="mb-4">
            <textarea wire:model="content" id="content" name="content" rows="4"
                class="block mt-1 w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-accent focus:ring-0 rounded-md shadow-sm"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
            <input wire:model="post_img" name="post_img" type="file" class="block w-full text-sm text-slate-500
      file:mr-4 file:py-2 file:px-4
      file:rounded-full file:border-0
      file:text-sm file:font-semibold
      file:bg-black-50 file:text-black-700
      hover:file:bg-black-100 
    " />
            @if ($post_img)
            <img src="{{ $post_img->temporaryUrl() }}">
            @endif
        </div>
        <x-primary-button>Post</x-primary-button>
    </form>

Livewire Component
    namespace App\Livewire\Pages;

// ...Other use namespace calls.
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;


class GroupPage extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $group_id = '';
    public $content = '';
    public $post_img;

    public function store_post()
    {
        $validated = $this->validate([
            'content' => 'required|string',
            'post_img' => 'nullable|image|max:2048', // Add validation rule here
        ]);

        $user_id = Auth::id();

        $post = Post::create([
            'content' => $validated['content'],
            'group_id' => $this->group_id,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
        ]);

        if ($this->post_img) {
            $filename = $this->post_img->hashName();

            $path = $this->post_img->storeAs('uploads/posts');

            Asset::create([
                'path' => $path,
                'type' => 'image',
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'post_id' => $post->id(),
            ]);
        }


        $this->reset('content');
        $this->post_img = null;

        session()->flash('success', 'Post created!');
    }

    // ...
}

Asset Model:
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Asset extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['path', 'type', 'user_id', 'post_id'];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}

Asset Migration:
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('assets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('path');
            $table->enum('type', ['image', 'video', 'file']);
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('post_id')->constrained('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('assets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
            $table->dropForeign(['post_id']);
        });

        Schema::dropIfExists('assets');
    }
};


Could you please to provide the code of the Asset model?

@AlexanderLeonBulatov Updated the question

When you save your post, do you have any errors on the screen or in laravel.log? Maybe, in this part of code
   Asset::create([
                'path' => $path,
                'type' => 'image',
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'post_id' => $post->id(),
            ]);

instead of
  'post_id' => $post->id(),

you should use
'post_id' => $post->id,

and when you save an image instead of
$path = $this->post_img->storeAs('uploads/posts');

you should use
 $path = $this->post_img->storeAs('uploads/posts/', $filename);


When i select the file, I get this error on screen The post_img failed to upload. and in the console 422 (Unprocessable Content)

I found the issue. It won't upload .jpeg but will upload .jpg. I am not sure why but that's why i am getting that error.

@WPdev11, may be you could show us a config of your storage?
